# Hide element behind transparent div

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make next animation: logo should be revealed by the div moving down. Div has a transparent background.

Is it possible to hide overlaying part of logo behind transparent div?

```
<div class="transparent">Some content</div>
<div class="logo"></div>

.transparent { position: relative }
.logo { position: absolute }
```

[image]

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do...obviously something can't be hidden behind a *transparent* div.

Comment: @Paulie_D the purpose of my question is, is there a trick that allow to hide element under transparent element?

Comment: Trick how?...it's **transparent**.

Comment: I would be very surprised if this is possible. The best you could do is to resize the logo so the edge aligns with the edge of the transparent panel

Comment: Create a JSFiddle with a full example so we can see exactly what you mean

Comment: Maybe CSS blend modes can help you a bit.

Comment: @Mustaghees sorry guys, this animation made in context of complex Angular app. Please see attached image

Answer (score 1):

I very much doubt if you could clip or mask anything behind a *transparent* element.

So, perhaps you need to rethink the **"hiding behind"** part and consider other options.

Perhaps animating the height:

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.transparent {
  height: 2em;
  line-height: 2em;
  border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
  position: relative;
}
.logo {
  height: 0;
  background: orange;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  width: 100px;
  transition: height 0.5s ease;
}
.transparent:hover .logo {
  height: 25px; /* assuming height is known */
}
```

```html
<div class="transparent">Some content
  <div class="logo"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe an effect like this may help that background of logo is the same as background of the `div` you are referring to as *transparent*.

Like this: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aOwZLJ

You will need to do some complex calculations, if the background is an image, in order to make it look as one element.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this too. Related mostly to hide some part of border.

```css
div {
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
div::after {
  content: "";
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid green;  
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  border-right: 0px;
  border-top:0px;
  border-bottom: 0px;
  top: -10px;
}

div::before {
  content: "";
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid green;  
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  border-right: 0px;
  border-top:0px;
  border-left: 0px;
  top: -1px;
  left: 10px;
  
}
```

```html
<div>

</div>
```

Comment: Could you please clarify your answers in the context of the questioner? Where is the transparent div and the logo in your answer?

Answer (score 0):

In 2021, it's actually possible, with some trickery.

First of all, `overflow-y:hidden` hides something from the bottom... unless it's upside down.

The wrapper should have any height, as long as it can serve as a cut off.

```
.wrapper {
    height: 70px;
    position: relative;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}
.logo {
    animation-name: stretch;
    animation-duration: 2s;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    transform-origin: top;
}
@keyframes stretch {
    0% {
        transform: translateY(110px) rotate(180deg);
    }

    100% {
        transform: translateY(40px) rotate(180deg);
    }
}
```

So now the logo will slide down from a seemingly transparent background.

Answer (score -1):

you can try giving visibility hidden property to hide the logo.

```css
visibility:hidden
```

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, it would be preferable if you could *demo* **exactly** how this resolves the users question.

Comment: Need to hide just overlaying part of logo